# How can I pass an image in the customView attribute of the LoadingIndicator?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, loading, indicator

I'm trying to create a Loading Indicator for my nativescript app and everything is working well but I wanted to add an specific image instead of the tradicional circle and for that I should (supposedly) put the image path of the Resource in the OptionsCommon's customView attribute, like this:

```
static loadingIndicator = new LoadingIndicator();
static optionsLoading: OptionsCommon = {
    mode: Mode.CustomView,
    customView: imageSource.fromResource("logo"),
    margin: 10,
    dimBackground: true,
    color: '#4B9ED6',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    userInteractionEnabled: false, 
    hideBezel: false, 
    android: {
      cancelable: false
    },
    ios: {
      square: false,
    }
};
```

Unfortunatelly when I test it shows up with this error:

```
JS: fromResource() is deprecated. Use ImageSource.fromResourceSync() instead.
JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setId' of undefined
JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildAt' of null
```

Also tried to call imageSource.fromResourceSync instead of the first one but it does not recognize it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer the plugin docs / code, `customView` only accepts a string which should be name of the image form resources Or it should be a custom native view. It can not be an ImageSource instance.

Comment: I just put the nome presented in the resources and worked fine. Thank you so much!